# ASP.NET MVC 4 DropdownListFor, Populating using LINQ from DBContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Having a hard time finding answer to this question (Google, StackOverflow and ASP.NET).

```
// Model
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> State { get; set; }

// View
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State, ????)

// Controller

using (var dbcontext = MyDbContext()) {

    // ??
}

return View(model);
```

I'm at a complete loss how to populate a mvc dropdownlistfor using LINQ from a DBContext.  I understand the DBContext thing and have one setup.  I'm not clear on how to construct a linq query and then pass that result (LIST?) to the DropDownListFor helper?  Using MS SQL and I have a States table (id, name).

Comment: a quick search found http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/11/dropdownlistfor-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx, http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/how-to-simple-html-dropdownlistfor-mvc-net/, http://peternewhook.com/2013/02/asp-net-mvc-selectlist-selectedvalue-dropdownlistfor/, http://hammadk.com/dropdownlistfor-example-c/, etc.  Did you have a more specific question?

Comment: Saw the first one and found it confusing. The specifics are using Linq with DBContexts. Although the first link has some example of that, it just didn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, in you model, include properties for what you want to bind to and the list of selections

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public string StateID { get; set; }
  .... // other properties
  public SelectList StateList { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller

```
// Initialise view model
MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
// Select the data to display (lots of ways to do this)
var states= from s in dbcontext.States
                 where s.SomeProperty == someValue // if you want to filer the results
                 select s
// Assign select list (this sets the value to the ID property and the display text to the Name property)
model.StateList = new SelectList(states, "ID", "Name");
// and if you want to set a default
model.StateID = "NY";
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateID, Model.StateList)
```

this will display the full name of the states in the `<select>` and bind the states ID value to the property `StateID`

Comment: I saw this exact answer in another SO post and found it a bit confusing. In your model you have CategoryID and CategoryList. How do these properties relate to my State property?  Do I need to change my State property from a IEnum to a SelectList? I think I need to see an example based on what I've posted for it to click.

Comment: If was just giving an example because I know nothing of your model. Is `State` typeof `string` and you want to select from a list of states, or is `State` a complex property with say properties  `int ID` and `string Name`?

Comment: State has an ID value which is the two letter abbrv for the state and Name is (naturally) the full name of the state. Both are strings.

Comment: I didn't realize I had to define two properties.

Comment: Just tested -- works like a charm.  Although I cannot use the 'using' keyword as my app faults saying the obj was already disposed. So, I guess Using isn't necessary here?

Comment: You accepted my answer an hour ago! You really should test before accepting :)

Comment: I knew the code was correct by looking at it.  I only needed to see an example to understand. Besides, if for some reason it turned out to be totally amiss, I could have unchecked accept -- wink.

Comment: How do i go about if i want to have the `StateId` be a property of a model that i made myself instead of just a string? Or is a dropdownlist limited to passing strings?

Comment: @Vahx, Not clear what your asking. The property `StateID` can be a value type such as `int` Everything sent to and from the browser is text, but the `DefaultModelBinder` will convert it to the type

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thx! Value type is the key word here for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
//dbcontext

using (var dbcontext = MyDbContext()) 
{
Dictionary<string, string> states = dbcontext .States.ToDictionary(t => t.StateID.ToString(), t => t.StateName.ToString());

}

// in controller attach this dictionary to ViewBag:

ViewBag.States=states;
```

// View

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.State,  new SelectList(ViewBag.States, "Key", "Value"))
```

Comment: There seems to be many ways to do this and its starting to click. Although your example doesn't seem to consider the model?  Or I'm I misreading it?

Comment: Well you can create property in model
in your model
Dictionary<string, string> states {get;set;}

//and in controller:
model.states=states; // return from dbcontext
// in view replace ViewBag.States with model.states.